# Finding lengths between the elements of an event

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix which has 1's,-1's and zeros.. say

```
state=[1; 1; -1; 1; -1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; -1; 1; 0; -1.........];
```

Say -1 is the start of an event and 0 contributes to the length  of it when its between (-1 and 1) as -1 remains the start and 1 is the end of event. But when 0 comes after a 1 that means it doesn't have any value to it as the event ended recently; can't take that into consideration.

So I need to get the number of such events that happened and also lengths of those events in the entire matrix for such events so my output would be

```
result=[2 10 2........]
```

and need the no of such events.

And in the above case I would exclude my first two indices which are 1's that doesn't contribute to anything.

It sounds simple but its been a while I got back to matlab. This is what I tried but it fails as it takes the zeros in between 1 and -1 as it should be excluded:

```
result=[find(state==-1)-find(state==1)];
```

which is wrong.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You say you have a matrix but your example is a vector? ie: How should edge cases be handled?

Comment: edited the question.
edge cases mean the first and last one..

Comment: What is about the `-1` at the end? Is the full expected output `[2 10 2 1]`? What would happen with an input `[-1 -1 0 1]` ?

Comment: edited the question.
edge cases mean the first and last one..

so as I mentioned -1 is the start so in the above example there are two ones before the -1 which we do not consider  if you look at the list -1 is the start.. 
so even in the end... I have -1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; and we don't consider the last two ones as they are end end. so the length would be 5 instead of 7. even if there are zeros after the 1 then exclude those.. like 
-1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; the length still remains 5 instead of seven as the event ended at the 1 already

Comment: even if there is just a  hanging -1 in the end which doesn't having a closing 1 that means that the evend didn't end so dont count that.

for example -1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; -1]
that means there is one event which has the length of 5 and last two indicii 0 and -1 doesn't count

Comment: +1 Interesting problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Find all starts and all ends.
2. For each start, find the end immediately after it.
3. Subtract each end found in step 2 minus each corresponding start, and don't forget to add 1.
4. The number of events is immediate from that.

The interesting part is step 2. [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) tests, for each combination of start and end, if the start is less than the end. Then the second output of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) gives the index of the *first* `true` value for each start, if any; and its first output tells you if there really was *some* `true` value, (that is, if the found index is valid).

```
starts = find(state(:)==-1);                              % // step 1
ends = find(state(:)==1);                                 % // step 1 
[valid, next_end] = max(bsxfun(@lt, starts.', ends));     %'// step 2
result = ends(next_end(valid)) - starts(valid) + 1;       % // step 3
number = numel(result);                                   % // step 4
```

Comment: Thanks Luis that's what I was looking for.. Thanks man you are a life saver. I guess I got what I needed. ill get back to you if I have more questions thanks again.